# toggle + fadein

Tags: jquery, toggle, fadein

I have a jquery function to toggle a div class, is it possible to have the "toggle" combined with a "fadein" effect?

```
function showDiv() {
    $("#mydiv").animate({
        "height": "toggle"
    }, {
        duration: 300
    })
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Need a fuller explanation of what, exactly, you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at:  [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Comment: Yes you are correct - I was trying it with fadeToggle but it didn't work - I realized then that I was using an old jquery version. It's working fine now - thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mydiv").animate({
        "height": "toggle"
    }, {
        duration: 300
    }, function(){
        $("#mydiv").fadeIn();
    }).
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Abdullah Abcoder, greatly appreciated!